# How to generate properties file from given template in shell script

Tags: bash, templates, properties

I am trying to create a config.properties file using a pre-defined template with the help of shell script. The properties file should have sections and its details.

Example: End result as properties file after running template using bash:

```
[dev]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:h2:mem:mem_test;MODE=Oracle
JDBC_USERNAME =
JDBC_PASSWORD =

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://localhost:8080/Central/api/AppService

[qa]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@qa-oracle:1521:qa
JDBC_USERNAME = qauser
JDBC_PASSWORD = qapass

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://qa-services/Central/api/AppService

[prod]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@prod-oracle:1521:prod
JDBC_USERNAME = scott
JDBC_PASSWORD = tiger

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://prod-services/Central/api/AppService
```

The template format which i have gives error if i try to make sections in properties file. Can someone please tell how to write the template for given properties file.

Comment: Throw away the back-quotes, just `SectionName=name` or `SectionName="name with spaces"`.

Comment: No idea what you want.  What script?  There is no code in your question.  What template?  Unclear, incomplete question IMHO.

Comment: @Nic3500 in bash we have a template for creating properties file. For more understanding go through this: Create new file from templates with bash script". So my question is same but i need a template with multiple sections.

Comment: In  that case we have to do some reasearch you already did. Please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).